# Why did the Sons of the Harpy attack?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Sons of the Harpy wanted to open fighting pits and wanted to continue with slave trade in Slavery Bay. So why did they attack even if Daenerys has already opened the fighting pits?

1. Why did they attack even after their demands are fulfilled?
2. What are their demands now?

Comment: They did not attack in the books.

Comment: Ok..thanks but is there any mention of any demand of sons of harpy other than opening fighting pits?

Comment: When Dany asks Hizdahr zo Loraq to stop the killings, they stop. When he is later removed as king, the killings begin. So it would seem they like Hizdahr as king. In the books. In the tv-show, they just seem to want to kill anyone allied with Dany.

Answer (score 8):

The Sons of the Harpy want Daenerys dead. They don't really have any demands that she could ever meet that would make them happy because her mere presence is what they object to.

Opening the pits wasn't a concession to the Sons of the Harpy but an attempt to prevent the rest of the city from rioting (which had already happened before) and to try and appease the richer citizens.

But until Dany is ousted, the former ruling families are back in power and slavery is legal again, the Sons of the Harpy are going to keep trying to kill her.

Comment: That makes sense ..thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this information from? 5 upvotes should require at least an indication where you read/heard this.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the correlation between how many *other people* upvoted my answer and what you seem to think it lacks... perhaps those 5 people just watched the same show I did, where this has been the central conflict of Dany's storyline for the whole season?

Comment: Well, what I mean is that you are expressing yourself incorrectly. "They don't really have any demands" should be "We have not heard them mention any demands". "They want Dany dead" should be "They have killed people connected to Dany, and probably want to kill her as well." You are stating many a things as facts, that are not facts. For example, in neither book nor show has The Sons of the Harpy given any kind of message, they have just killed people.

Comment: If we have not seen it on TV then it doesn't exist. "We have not heard them give any demands" means "they have no demands." IMO, you are nitpicking the wording of the answer to an unrealistic degree with no real complaints about its content.

Comment: Well, there is a point, and that is that in the books, the Sons of the Harpy seemed mollified by Dany's marriage to Hizdahr. In other words, in the books, they did not want Dany dead. In the tv-show, they went ahead and attacked anyway after the marriage, so the comparison fails. Still, it is a favourite theory of mine, that The Green Grace is The Harpy, and that she was not all too opposed to Dany's rule, just so long as Mereen's values and culture lived on.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think it is worth arguing about. I've said my piece, and I hope you got something constructive from it. It was not my intention to offend you.